# Loop through each row of a range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-2003

This is one of those things that I'm sure there's a built-in function for (and I may well have been told it in the past), but I'm scratching my head to remember it.

How do  I loop through each row of a multi-column range using Excel VBA?  All the tutorials I've been searching up seem only to mention working through a one-dimensional range...

Comment: http://codevba.com/excel/for_each_cell_in_range.htm#.Xyd8qCgzaUk

Answer (score 175, accepted):

```
Dim a As Range, b As Range

Set a = Selection

For Each b In a.Rows
    MsgBox b.Address
Next
```

Answer (score 170):

Something like this:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:C2")

For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell in row.Cells
    'Do Something
  Next cell
Next row
```

Comment: I tried this and row.Columns worked--not row.Cells

Comment: What is "cell" in this context? I.E., "B3" or the contents of "B3"

Answer (score 11):

Just stumbled upon this and thought I would suggest my solution. I typically like to use the built in functionality of assigning a range to an multi-dim array (I guess it's also the JS Programmer in me).

I frequently write code like this:

```
Sub arrayBuilder()

myarray = Range("A1:D4")

'unlike most VBA Arrays, this array doesn't need to be declared and will be automatically dimensioned

For i = 1 To UBound(myarray)

    For j = 1 To UBound(myarray, 2)

    Debug.Print (myarray(i, j))

    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Assigning ranges to variables is a very powerful way to manipulate data in VBA.

Comment: Two main advantages to favour it: 1) the array method is **always faster** than looping through a range, 2) it' s simple and you can use it in **both directions** and write the array back after some calculations: `Range("A1:D4") = myarray`. **Note:** `Dim myarray` as variant; pay attention to the fact that it's a *1based* 2dim array by default

Answer (score 7):

In Loops, I always prefer to use the `Cells` class, using the R1C1 reference method, like this:

```
Cells(rr, col).Formula = ...
```

This allows me to quickly and easily **loop** over a **Range** of cells easily:

```
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

c = GetTargetColumn() ' Or you could just set this manually, like: c = 1

With Sheet1 ' <-- You should always qualify a range with a sheet!

    For r = 1 To 10 ' Or 1 To (Ubound(MyListOfStuff) + 1)

        ' Here we're looping over all the cells in rows 1 to 10, in Column "c"
        .Cells(r, c).Value = MyListOfStuff(r)

        '---- or ----

        '...to easily copy from one place to another (even with an offset of rows and columns)
        .Cells(r, c).Value = Sheet2.Cells(r + 3, 17).Value


    Next r

End With
```