# excel VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I have form with three text to put this values on same row to different column.
this works fine.
I have created this function to verify if combination of text1 and text2 exists on some row yet.
but it verify only the first of condition.

```
Function kontr() As Boolean
Dim endRow As Long
endRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To endRow
    If (ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value <> UserForm1.TextBox1.Text And ActiveSheet.Range("F" & i).Value <> UserForm1.TextBox2.Text) Then

   kontr = True
Else
    MsgBox ("Exists!")
    kontr = False
    End If

Next i
End Function
```

can someone help with this?

Comment: instead of a `for` loop, you could use `COUNTIFS()`. Probably simpler and faster.

Comment: Are you sure the logic is correct? From the description it sounds to me like you want `If (ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text And ActiveSheet.Range("F" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox2.Text) Then` `kontr = True` `Exit Function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Find`. It is faster. Your code is checking in the same row at the same time. I am guessing that you want to check if the values exists `anywhere` in the respective columns.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Public Function kontr() As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:=UserForm1.TextBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        Set bCell = .Columns(5).Find(What:=UserForm1.TextBox2.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If aCell Is Nothing And bCell Is Nothing Then
            kontr = True
        Else
            MsgBox ("Exists!")
            kontr = False
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is to do with the way you calculated the endrow, amend that line to:

```
endrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
```

To get the last row on Column C with data.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why not rewrite condition in *positive boolean logic* ?

Suppose you want to check if **both** `UserForm1` texts (`TextBox1` and `TextBox2`) **do match** the values of **two columns** (`C` and `F`). In other words you want to check **if the combination** exists in some row.

Then you should check for:

```
If (ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text _
  And ActiveSheet.Range("F" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox2.Text) Then
   matchFound = True
   MsgBox ("Combination Exists in C and F!")
   Exit For
Else
   matchFound = False;
End If
```

#### What about *aborting the filtering* after found a match ?

The `Exit For` will exit the for-loop after match was found. See [Excel VBA - exit for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414969/ddg#9415163).

#### Looping through ranges

```
Dim C_to_F_Columns As Range, cRow As Range
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set C_to_F_Columns = Range("C2:F" & lastrow)

For Each cRow In C_to_F_Columns.Rows
   cValue = cRow.Offset(0,0).Value
   fValue = cRow.Offset(0,2).Value

   ' insert your matching logic here
Next
```

See [looping through a range of 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449083/looping-through-a-range-of-2-columns).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure might be there are whitespaces in the text, so this wasn't satisfying the condition

Try using trim
TRIM( text ) method

Comment: good point! Comparing _text_s can be always spiced-up using some __trimming__ or  even __ignoreCase__ using `UCase` or `LCase` string-functions: `equalsIgnoreCase = ( LCase(str1) = LCase(str2) )`